# What does exactly "temporary failure in name resolution" mean in the DNS protocol? - RFC 1035

Tags: dns, analysis

I've looked into the [DNS specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) but can't find that there.

Situation: from time to time, a `wget` query says for a public server name, there is a "Temporary failure in name resolution." After that it works again.

What does this mean, exactly? And where to look for the problem source?

- A verbose DNS query with more information about the protocol error?
- Logs of the DNS server?

Answer (score 3):

It *doesn't* have an exact meaning. It's a generic "this might work later but not now" error, kinda like HTTP 500.

- It could be that your local DNS cache (if you have one) was unable to reach the recursive resolver. For example, if you run dnsmasq.
- It could be that the recursive resolver was unable to reach an authoritative server (at any level). Sometimes resolvers seem to give up early even if just one authoritative server is down, despite more being available for that domain.
- It could be that the recursive resolver received unacceptable responses from the authoritative servers (e.g. if it encountered a lame delegation).
- It could indicate an internal server error, e.g. an authoritative server can return SERVFAIL if it suddenly became unable to retrieve records from the database.
- It could even indicate a DNSSEC validation failure, which itself has several causes (expired signature, key mismatch, unable to fetch signatures...)
- In some cases it even indicates a *permanent* issue, e.g. systemd-resolved returns SERVFAIL whenever it refuses to resolve a single-label name via DNS (to avoid leaking hostnames).

The original DNS packet format didn't leave much space for elaborate status codes, but with EDNS we now have [RFC 8914](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8914/) which allows the DNS server to report a more precise error. However, very few resolvers support it yet, and even if they do, your OS won't know to look for it.

So if it's likely that the problem is on the domain host's side, you can try asking a different resolver using `dig` – e.g. CloudFlare supports the extended error reporting:

```
$ dig dnssec-failed.org @1.1.1.1

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 5960

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; EDE: 6 (DNSSEC Bogus)
```

Even without this, DNSSEC is easily the prime suspect – if even public resolvers keep returning this error code, put the domain name in DNSViz and it'll display the signature chain along with all issues it finds.

On the other hand, if public resolvers are fine with the domain, then your local resolver most likely has trouble with actually retrieving the signatures. (It might be caused by an upstream server not having EDNS support and not understanding that it's being asked to provide more data than usual.)

Authoritative server problems can be discovered using `dnstrace -s. example.com` which queries each of them directly, from root downwards, and will show any which are down or not accepting the queries that they're meant to accept.

In other cases, you'll just need to look at your resolver's logs (if it has any) and try to narrow down the issue by pointing `dig` at various different servers. For example, if you're using a local cache (be it on the computer or the home router), try bypassing it.

Answer (score 0):

This message means that wget failed to resolve the domain name used as parameter.

In your case, I see two main possible cause :

- problem with your domain name server
- problem with your (internet) connection (preventing you to joining your name server)

You can try to change your name server.

If you are not using name resolution for local resources, you can set `8.8.8.8` as name server.
It's google name server and it's pretty reliable.

If you still have this problem, it's probably a temporary connection problem preventing you to join the google DNS Server.

If you don't have problem with the new DNS Server, the problem probably come from the old DNS Server.